# How to ensure unique name for MEF plugins

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I'm using `DirectoryCatalog()` and `[ImportMany]` to import multiple plugins of the same type from multiple assemblies. A list of all available plugins will be presented to the user to choose from.

The exporting assemblies will be developed by third parties and hence there must be a guarantee that the names of imported plugins are unique.

I can't see a way of doing this except by attaching the filename to the plugin full name (e.g. `fileName.assemblyName.pluginName`) however, I can't find the file name of a specific assembly anywhere. All fields in the catalog that have a reference to the filename do not seem to change if the filename changes (I've tested this by making a copy of `plugin.dll` and named it `plugin_2.dll`, the catalog reported `plugin.dll` as the file name for all imports, in `Assemblies[n]`, `CodeBase` and other fields) The only place where I could find the actual names of the files is in `Assemblies.LoadedFiles[]` but I don't know how associate which plugin to which loaded file.

If there's a way of getting the filename or if there's another way of guaranteeing unique plugin names, please let me know.

Comment: You could place each MEF part inside its own folder, then you don't have to think about filename clashes.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing would probably be to use [export metadata](https://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exports%20and%20Metadata&referringTitle=Guide) and have each plugin provide a unique identifier (a GUID for example) for their plugin - then it's just a matter of examining the metadata.

Depending on your specific case though you might even be able to get this information without using export metadata. If for example you're importing `IPlugin` instances and you know that each concrete implementation will be implemented in the plugin assembly, you could import the plugins and get the assembly location by calling `myPlugin.GetType().Assembly.Location`